# How do I create an MFC ComboBox with search

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ccombobox

I need a combobox in an Windows MFC application that has a search feature. It should work so that if you start typing something that matches one or more items in the list, the combobox should drop-down and display those items. Kinda like popular ajax-based search boxes on the web

Do you
- know of any control that provides this functionality?
- have a link to information on how to create such functionality myself?
- have ideas on how to do this that you could share?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a handler for the `CBN_EDITCHANGE` event, your handler willö be called every time the user changes the text in the edit field.

In this Handler, call the `CComboBox::FindString()` method to see if the typed text exists in any of your combobox entries. If it does, call `CComboBox::SetCurSel()` to select it.

Answer (score -1):

It's a Win32 api FAQ.
See Adv. Win32 api ng news://194.177.96.26/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
(you don't need at all CBN_EDITCHANGE. It's automatic with api)

Comment: I don’t know how to view this article.

Answer (score -1):

Full access to the edit box of the combo box:

```
CEdit *pEdit = (CEdit *)pComboBox->GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
```